# Returing Selected option from dropdown to HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML drop down list which I need to be able to get the selected option and return it later on in my code:

```
<select name="quantitySelected" id="quantitySelected" onchange="javascript: getSelected()">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

I have managed to create a javascript that gets the selected option but I then can't work out how to pull that value back into my html:

```
<script> 
    function getSelected() {
    var x = document.getElementById("quantitySelected").selectedIndex;
    var y = document.getElementById("quantitySelected").options;
    var selectedItem = y[x].text;
    document.getElementById('SelectedItem').innerHTML = selectedItem;
    }
</script>
```

I am then trying to return this value here so that it can be sent to my next page:

```
<td><button><a href="Update.php?Quantity=HERE">Update</button></td>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why not just use a `form`, and submit the value of the `select`?

Comment: Hi there, would you be able to give me an example of some code please? thanks

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I see none.

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to put that there

Comment: Where's your element with the id "SelectedItem" ?

Comment: I was trying out using something like this......<td><button><a href="Update.php?Quantity=id='SelectedItem">Update</button></td>

Comment: You're also missing the name tag in your select. Won't work without it

Answer (score 0):

Also the select element may need to have an onchange event handler added to it so  it can call the getSelected function when its value changes

Comment: I have added an on change handler which now runs the script each time the selected item changes but I am still struggling to find a way to output my selected item variable from the javascript into the html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to update the href attribute of the link from the onchange handler, first remove the query string you already have there then do something like.

```
link = document.getElementById("your link id");
link.href  = link.href + "?Quantity=" +selectedItem;
```

That hopefully should work.